# Are custom UIContentView / UIContentConfiguration implementations incompatible with Swift strict concurrency?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Let's say that I have this fairly minimal implementation of custom configuration and content view in my app:

```swift
struct ExampleContentConfiguration {
  let name: String
  let score: Int
}

extension ExampleContentConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
  func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
    return ExampleContentView(configuration: self)  // [1]
  }
  
  func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> ExampleContentConfiguration {
    return self
  }
}

final class ExampleContentView: UIView, UIContentView {
  var configuration: UIContentConfiguration  // [2]
  
  init(configuration: ExampleContentConfiguration) {
    self.configuration = configuration
    super.init(frame: .zero)
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

The two protocols that underlie this have no concurrency annotations. On the other hand, `UIView` (and its subclasses) are marked as `@MainActor`. So when I set the **Strict Concurrency Checking** build setting to **Complete**, Xcode reports two issues at the marked lines:

1. Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init(configuration:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context.
2. Main actor-isolated property 'configuration' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement.

(Confusingly, if I look at the generated interface for `UIListContentView`, its `configuration` property has a `@MainActor` attribute.)

What am I missing here? How could these types implement these protocols while adhering to the strict concurrency rules?

Answer (score 1):

Follow up: it appears that [in the beta iOS 17 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentview?changes=latest_major), the `UIContentView` protocol, its members, and the method `UIContentConfiguration.makeConfiguration()` have all been marked with the `@MainActor` attribute.